# Which method of 'Django Serializer' do I need to customize?

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, django-serializer

The frontend sends the json in an array.

I received the value with difficulty as shown in ex) below.

ex)

```
applier_phone = data.get('phone')[0]
applier_name = data.get('name')[0]
applier_birth = data.get('birth')[0]
applier_gender = data.get('gender')[0]
```

But I want to get the value using Serializer.

In this case, which method of Serializer do I need to customize?

Comment: you can override `to_internal_value`, converting the arrays into a single object

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think the best solution would be to modify the Serializer in itself. Rather i would suggest to modify the Json Object so the serializer detects it as by the initial schema od your Model.
This will let the Serializer still be usable for multiple case and instances.
If you still want to take the first approach i would suggest you may intervene in any of the .create() .update() , or even validate() methods for re-structuring your JSON object.

Comment: Thank you! That's a really good suggest.

Comment: If you found the answer useful you can vote it.